# Fetching Tagged people in photo using Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am an ios Developer and i am Loggin in to the app using Facebook (Graph API).

I have fetched all the images from the facebook in which I am tagged , but i also need to fetch the list of the user which are tagged in the images i am tagged in.

Please Revert back.

Comment: Are you asking a question here? If you're asking Facebook to revert a change in their SDK then you've come to the wrong place as this isn't Facebook. If you want some help with something then please post some more code and add a bit more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of users tagged in a photo-

```
/{photo-id}/tags
```